# Count date from the date field

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I have two dropdownlists- A year and a month one. I have to print the gridview if the records are existing for the whole month. For this, I have the following code. I know my SQL query is totally wrong.

```
con.Open();
        //count dates 
        string cmd = "SELECT COUNT(EXTRACT(DATE FROM Duty_Date)) FROM DoctorActivity WHERE MONTH=@MONTH AND YEAR=@YEAR AND ([User_Id]=@User_Id)";
        SqlCommand commd = new SqlCommand(cmd, con);
        commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Id", DropDownList1.Text);
        commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MONTH", DropDownList2.Text);
        commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YEAR", DropDownList3.Text);
        int dateCount = (int)commd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (dateCount >= 30)
        {

            //show computer id and status in gridview
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
        }
```

I'm still new to working with SQL queries. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't get, What is the problem?

Comment: Can you tell what is your SQL Table Design? Or what is the datatype of Column Duty_Date?

Comment: I have a Duty_Date field in my sql database. I want to extract only the date part and count it to see if it is more than 30(depends on the month- could be 30 or 31, not considering feb for now). So if the records are existing from say 01/01/2016 to 31/01/2016 then I want to print the gridview. Please suggest me the correct SQL query to achieve this.

Comment: The data type of Duty_Date is date type. The other columns of my Table consists of records or data against those dates.

Comment: When you say " records are existing for the whole month." do you mean record should exist every day of the month ?

Comment: which db you are using? mysql or sql server?

Comment: @cvraman Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

`Extract` is MySql function, In Sql server 2008 to extract datepart you could use

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

or if you are using older version you could use

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @your_date))
```

So you have to change your query to something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct convert(date,Duty_Date)) FROM DoctorActivity WHERE MONTH=@MONTH AND YEAR=@YEAR AND [User_Id]=@User_Id
```

Use distinct if there will be a repetition in duty_date field

Comment: I have used the following code, could you tell me what's wrong with my syntax in the month and year part  - 'string cmd = "SELECT COUNT(distinct convert(date,Duty_Date)) FROM DoctorActivity WHERE convert(month,Duty_Date)=@MONTH AND convert(year,Duty_Date)=@YEAR AND [User_Id]=@User_Id";'

Comment: Refer the above link you have to use date part function to extract month and year part from datetime

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `CONVERT(date, yourdate)` to extract date part in sql server, Change date extraction part in your query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(convert(date,Duty_Date)) FROM DoctorActivity
```